# Android Room library error: Cannot find getter for field

Tags: java, android

I get this error but I couldn't find any solution. I tried many things but still I'm getting this code.

**My code is:**
https://justpaste.it/4di3y

**The error:**

> error: Cannot find getter for field.
>   ( private Long fie_id )

How I can fix it?

Comment: Post you code here rather than on an external site.

Comment: I downvoted for not posting the code.

Comment: remove private, it's working for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of

```
public Long getId() {
    return fie_id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.fie_id = id;
}
```

Do

```
public Long getFie_id() {
    return fie_id;
}

public void setFie_id(Long fie_id) {
    this.fie_id = fie_id;
}
```

Comment: I changed private to public and it's works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Cellojaan Variables should be private, and the constructors public, that's the principle of encapsulation.

Comment: for clarification, PrimaryKey id, setId(Long id) this.fie_id = id. was it calling PrimaryKey id?

Comment: sorry I changed public to private :) before id vas public when I change private it's works for me.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug but in regular circumstances the class fields should be private and assign a setter/getter to access them for encapsulation reasons. But Room requires them to be public at all times.

Comment: I think it is not for private/public as stated above comment.
For my case columnInfo name and member variable needs to be same. 
For example- 
           @ColumnInfo(name = "word")
           and   private String word;  

          and getter methode like --  public String getWord();

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you don't believe me but i have to say. I am using Mac and that problem was about the Computer Language. I was using Turkish Language and i have changed to English and that problem was gone after Invalidate Cache and Restart.

As summary:

- **Set MacOSX language as English** (SystemPreferences -> Language & Region)
- Open Android Studio and Perform **Invalidate Caches And Restart** (File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart)

Comment: Azerbaijan language primary set in Preferred language for that reason I faced same issue

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin room does not allow defining variables in entity class start of  'i' character. I had the same error. I solved it, albeit difficult.
Replace id with pId and it will be fine.
For example;

```kotlin
  val isrc: String? = "",
```

instead of

```kotlin
  val albumIsrc: String? = "",
```

If you change the variable in this way, the error will be resolved.
Happy codding.

**Note :** if system language of your computers is Turkish, this case does.

Comment: I did what you said was my friend's computer's language was Turkish and the problem was solved. Thanks @fevziomurtekin

Comment: This answer solved my problem. It was a problem that I spent time on for long periods of time. Thanks a lot @fevziomurtekin

Answer (score 5):

Change all the access modifier to "public". This will solve the issue.

Instead of:

```
@PrimaryKey
private Long fie_id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")

private String name;
```

Use:

```
@PrimaryKey
public Long fie_id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")

public String name;
```

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the naming of your `PrimaryKey`. The signature of your getter and setter should correspond to the name of the variable. Otherwise, `Room` can't find it.

Which means that the variable `id` should have `getId()`, and variable `fie_id` should have `getFie_id()` as a getter, the same goes for the setters. So, either rename your `PrimaryKey` or name your getters and setters accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was because of an uncapitalized "m". The below works:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "foo")
private String mFoo;

public String getMFoo() {
    return mFoo;
}

public void setMFoo(String foo) {
    this.mFoo = foo;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "foo")
private String mFoo;

public String getmFoo() {
    return mFoo;
}

public void setmFoo(String foo) {
    this.mFoo = foo;
}
```

Also don't forget to specify the new column in your migration. Something like:

```
val MIGRATION_2_3: Migration = object : Migration(2, 3) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE myDataObj "
                    + " ADD COLUMN foo TEXT")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to match the name of the setter function as the variable name declared.
Forex.
There is a boolean variable declared like 
 
**private boolean attachment_status;**

It's getter should be like this 
 
**public boolean getattachment_status(){ 

  return attachment_status 

}**

or u can do like this 
 
**public boolean getAttachment_status(){ 

return attachment_status 

}**

I declared my getter like this and I was getting the same error 
 
**public boolean getAttachment(){ 

  return attachment_status 

}**

but I refactor it and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

During your programs lifecycle if the **encapsulation** is incorrect then confusion happens. After viewing your code it seems might be attempting to access something from an eternal class. PrimaryKey id is being called instead of the passed value setId( id ).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the variable from private to protected worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable public:
Private --> Public

Answer (score 0):

It is better to stick with documantation. The structures are sensitive. [link of documantation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data) 
 Sample :

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int id;   

@NotNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "note")
public  String mNote;

public Note(@NotNull String mNote) {
    this.mNote = mNote;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@NotNull
public String getNote() {
    return this.mNote;
}}
```

Had same problem `Clear` and `Rebuild` the project options are the answer somehow after the change.

Answer (score 0):

for getter in setter, just follow the Pattern get/set[A-Z]last lenght-1 of the field just like in the example ( field: mWord)

```
@Entity(tableName = "words")
```

public class Word {

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "word")
private String mWord;

public Word(@NonNull String mWord) {
    this.mWord = mWord;
}

public String getMWord() {
    return mWord;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Only need to change is fied scope update as "public" instead of "private".

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1403

Answer (score 0):

If everything is correct, then I have observe this issue mostly in a case of variable kind of pId, uId etc.

change variable name from

> private Long **pId**;

to

> private Long **pid**;

And generate getter and setter using IDE.